# Google analytics client id cookie not set

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

First of all, this is first time I'm trying to setup Google Analytics and Tag Manager and need client id from `_ga` cookie.

I thought that including snippet gtm.js is enough but `_ga` is not set after that

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js? 
id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

So my question do I need to include also snippet for `analitycs.js` or `gtm.js` is enough but I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: GTM snippet is enough, but you aslo need to fire GA Tag, after that you should see _ga cookie. If you still don't can you post your GA tag setup inside GTM?

Comment: @Matus: thanks for reply, as I said completely new in GA didn't get what you mean neither by `but you aslo need to fire GA Tag` nor `GA tag setup`. what I have is
<script>
            // Google Analytics
            dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({ "environment": some_value });
        </script>

Comment: Google Tag Manager (what you have) is something different from Google Analytics. Google Analytics tracks data, GTM is used to inject tags in your page. If you are going for a tracking setup with GTM you need to include your GTM code (as you have done), then go the GTM interface, create a new Google Analytics tag with the ID of your GA property, then attach a trigger (a rule that makes the tag appear on your page), publish GTM and only then you will have tracking. Looks like more effort than just dumpin in Analytics code, but makes configuration a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: Not sure if I get all, can you please let me know is this will work in case we have a multiple environments and every one should be separate: If it is possible can you please attach some screen shots so I can at least have point to dig into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize you need to follow these steps to start tracking to Google Analytics via GTM (meaning to se _ga cookie created):

1. implement GTM to page
2. create in the GTM management interface pageview GA Tag with desired tracking ID UA-XXXX
3. assign trigger to this Tag - probably All Pages which is automatically created
4. preview the tag - to see if its working and you are getting real-time hits on your page in Google Analytics interface
5. publish the changes to the GTM container

After these steps everything should work fine and the cookie should be created.

In case of need refer to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28d60ejfk3s

Comment: Thanks, helped to tune up :)

Answer (score 0):

First create variable on GTM type 1st-party cookie

Variable - GA-COOKIE
1st-party cookie 
On Cookie Name = _ga

Obtain ClientID from the Cookie
Create one custom javascript an put this function

```
function() {
    var id = {{GA-COOKIE}};
    var aux;
    aux = id.split(".");
    return aux[2]+"."+aux[3];
  }
```

This function return the clientID